# Structuring .Net Core web application with api authentication + api services

Tags: api, authentication, .net-core, state

I am currently looking into splitting up a .Net Core project and I am not sure on which technologies to employ.

Lets say that I wanted to create a website where authenticated users could look op book titles:

I would like the project structured like this:
.Net Core web application using MVC (All UI in here)
.Net Core Wep api for authentication users (Authenticating users against database here)
.Net Core wep api for Book titles (return titles if user is validated)

Application flow would be the following:

User goes to UI web page and is met by login-screen. User enters username/password and then UI will send a login request to the Authentication-API. Authentication API should return some sort of data that the UI can store in the users session to verify that the user is validated for the next period of time.

When the user want's to get the book titles, the WEB UI should send the existing authentication data to Book Titles API. The book title api should then verify that the user is still authenticated and return the book titles if so.

My question is, what is "best practice" in regards to this setup. I have read a lot of different things about JWT tokens/JWE, Cookies and so forth, and I am having a bit of trouble finding my way in it.

Could my Authentication API use Identity framework, and could that information be passed around to other API's or should I use cookie authentication and how would do that?

In the project future I would like to be able to create an App that should also be able to access the Authentication and Book title API's not worrying about the .Core UI project.

Is there anyone out there who can point me in the correct direction here or have some good recent articles/references I could look into.

Best regards

Comment: Is your application oging to perform authentication or you are thinking of intergating with some identiy server? Now a days application re-direct or use 3rd part IDP or SSO techniques like openAM, google SSO, facebook etc ?

Comment: @Sohan My application is going to provide the authentication there are currently no plans  to use 3rd party for this.

Comment: Ok, on top of my mind  I have, you can use Identiy server in your application. Check my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand your thoughts around designing the solution. The things you have mentioned above looks appropriate and do not see any issues. But I would like to recommend few things when it comes to selecting the right authentication framework

If you are thinking to integrate your application with some IDP like google or okta etc then you need to define the protocol you will be using. One of most popular is [OIDC](https://openid.net/connect/).
Look for some of standard flows for you application. If you are having client-server architecture, you can opt for either implicit flow (less recommended due to security issues ) or authorization code flow

.Net has very nice support on using OIDC for application.

When using the OIDC, you are eligible for session store, access_toke which is Shot TTL token and can be used between application to communicate with each other.Know more about it [here](https://auth0.com/docs/tokens/access-tokens)

The complete authentication process with right flow and integrated application will be taken care by IDP, you just need right configuration, library/framework support  to do it.
Using OIDC also  give you benefit to not fall into any [OWASP](https://owasp.org/) issues.
On top of that you just need to deal with authorization logic which is very common and application specific
One of IDP you can try for free and on cloud is [Okta](https://www.okta.com/)

Another option if you are using your own authentication framework,
You can implement you own identity server framework
Check this articles [Using .net core with identity server](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/asp-net-core-authentication-with-identityserver4/). You can host you identity server or expose API of same using your application.
Git hug link for [IdentityServer4](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4)

Answer (score 1):

You can find a ready made solution with sample projects using this solution on below git repository:
[IdentityServer4 Implementation with ASP.NET Core](https://github.com/nksherani/IdentityServer4WithASP.NETCoreDemo)

You can find there an auth server which authenticates the username/password and gives back token. That token is used to access an MVC app as well as a secure API.